# How can I configure ffserver to support rtmp instead of http?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, mediaelement.js, ffserver

I grab the image from my camera using ffmpeg and the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 http://10.172.180.235:8090/feed2.ffm
```

and on other machine (with the ip mentioned above) I have the ffserver running with the following config file:

```
HttpPort 8090
HttpBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 3000
CustomLog -
<Stream stat.html>
    Format status
    ACL allow localhost
    ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
    ACL allow 10.172.180.199
    ACL allow 10.172.180.216
    ACL allow 10.172.180.215
</Stream>
<Feed feed2.ffm>
    File /tmp/feed2.ffm
    FileMaxSize 1G 
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
    ACL allow 10.172.180.199
    ACL allow 10.172.180.216
    ACL allow 10.172.180.236
    ACL allow 10.172.180.109
</Feed>
<Stream live.flv>
    Format flv
    Feed feed2.ffm

    VideoCodec libx264
    VideoFrameRate 30
    VideoBitRate 800
    VideoSize 1280x720 
    AVOptionVideo crf 23
    AVOptionVideo preset medium
    AVOptionVideo me_range 16
    AVOptionVideo qdiff 4
    AVOptionVideo qmin 10
    AVOptionVideo qmax 51
    AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
 NoAudio
    AudioCodec aac
    Strict -2
    AudioBitRate 128
    AudioChannels 2
    AudioSampleRate 44100
    AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
</Stream>
```

And that works, I can stream video in flv over http... But now I would like to use rtmp, becase I want to display the live stream on my webpage with some player. I wanted to use the [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/), but it seems like in the latest versions it doesn't support live video any more... I found [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/), but to stream live content there I need the rtmp protocol, so that's the cause of my question.
Thanks for your help